# Ajax dont send email, but status is 200

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a problem with my Ajax, I have code:

```
    const sendForm = function () {
        action = 'contact';

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                const getMessageSend = document.querySelector("#messageSend");
                getMessageSend.classList.add("message-send");
                getMessageSend.innerText = "Thank you for sending an email. You will receive an answer shortly.";
            } else {
                const getMessageSendError = document.querySelector("#messageSendError");
                getMessageSendError.classList.add("message-send");
                getMessageSendError.classList.add("message-send-error");
                getMessageSendError.innerText = "An error occurred and the email was not sent.";
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("post", action, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    };

    const sendMail = function() {

        options.form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let validate = true;
            const elementsRequired = document.querySelectorAll(":scope [formHr]");

            [].forEach.call(elementsRequired, function(element) {
                const type = element.type.toUpperCase();

                if (type === 'TEXT') {
                    if (!validateText(element)) {validate = false;}
                }

                if (type === 'EMAIL') {
                    if (!validateEmail(element)) {validate = false;}
                }

                if (type === 'NUMBER') {
                    if (!validateNumber(element)) {validate = false;}
                }

                if (type === 'FILE') {
                    if (!validateFile(element)) {validate = false;}
                }

                if (type === 'CHECKBOX') {
                    if (!validateCheckbox(element)) {validate = false;}
                }

            });
            if (validate) {
                sendForm();
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        });

    };
```

My action file is correct write, because when I remove Ajax and try send email using only PHP, email is sending correctly.

Ajax return status 200:

```
POST http://mypage.com/contact [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 231ms]
```

but the e-mail does not reach the mailbox, I must add `this.submit()` after `sendForm()`, then e-mail is sending correctly. But when I add `this.submit()` the page is reload, but I don't want the page to be reloaded.

Comment: Observe your server logs. If the response status is 200, that means there was no error from the client. In any case, delivering mails is server's work, JS cannot do anything about it.

Comment: @31piy So why when I send an e-mail using PHP (I am removing AJAX), the e-mail is sent correctly. However, when I use AJAX, e-mail does not reach the mailbox. This means that the server is working properly.

Comment: You're missing the point. When you're using AJAX, you're using JavaScript. When you're not using AJAX, you are most probably submitting your form to the server directly. But in any case, AJAX alone is not responsible for mails not getting delivered. You need to observe what's going on the server as well.

Comment: @31piy It is shared hosting, I do not have the ability to check what is happening on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is twofold:

1. You are not sending a body with your request (the xmlhttp.send() has not arguments). See here for usage, and pay attention to the POST example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send
2. Your server is returning a 200 when it doesn't have all of the parameters it needs. It would probably be beneficial to have it validate that all the parameters it needs are provided, and return 422 (Unprocessable Entity) or some other relevant code if it doesn't have enough information to process the request.

When you call this.submit(), it is actually submitting the form (which will contain the parameters). In order to send the ajax request, you will need to basically take the values from the form, construct a body your server will accept, and then send it.